# Why does bash man page read that special parameters "may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed"?

Tags: bash

`man bash` reads:

> ```
> Special Parameters
>        The shell treats several parameters specially.
>        These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
> ```

Well, `shift` changes both `@` and `*` (in the same way, sure). And `set -- one two three` actually assigns whatever I want to `@` and `*`.

So am I misinterpreting what the `man` pages says?

Comment: Shift, while does modify the special positional parameters, is not an assignment operation.

Comment: Ah. Well so it's just about not being able to assign those values through `var=value`? I mean `set -- value` is doing to `@` exactly the same thing as `var=value` does to `var`.

Comment: I guess the downvotes are because the question is _not useful_, right, downvoters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to special parameters. You can't use the assignment operator (`1=foo`, `@=(foo bar)`, `?=0`, …). You can't use the assignment parameter expansion construct (`${1=foo}`, …).

Sure, you can modify them, but you have to use an indirect method other than assignment, such as the `set` (with non-option arguments) or `shift` builtins to set the positional parameters and `$#`, `set` (with options) to modify `$-`, running a command to set `$?`, etc.

As an exception, you can actually assign to `_`, although it usually won't stick (`_=foo a=$_` sets `a` to `foo` and `_` to the empty string).

Comment: Can you say something more about the _won't stick_ part? `a` being `foo` after those two commands seems reasonable, but why is `_` empty?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis In bash, `_` is a special variable that's automatically set to the name of the last executed command. For example `true; echo $_; echo $_` prints `true` and `echo`. You can assign to `_`, but as soon as the command is executed, bash modifies it. The only way to observe an assignment to `_` is to do it during the expansion of the command, before the command is executed, as in my example which performs two assignments within the same simple command.

Comment: Oh, sure, it's obvious. The same way a change to `@` implies a similar change to `*` and a change to `#`, for instance. Thanks. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

The core of your question resides in what an assignment is. `man bash` apparently does not define it, but [POSIX specification has a word on it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_23):

> 4.23 Variable Assignment
>
> In the shell command language, a word consisting of the following
>   parts:
>
> varname=value

You may modify the special parameters `$@` and `$*` by some shell built-in means, but you can't actually write an assignment to them. They were wisely chosen, I'd say, because it indeed would look very unnatural to write `*=string`, even to not so trained eyes.